# Image resizing inside tableviewcell

Tags: ios, image

I ran into a problem that can not solve 2 days. On the server image and come before inserting them in the box, I cut them on the client to fit the screen. Everything is good but the images change randomly height. Now the height is calculated independently - in proportion to the width.
Normal image:

[image]

Bad image

[image]

I can not ask explicitly UIImageView because I dynamically I rely all the cells to different devices.

My resize function:

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage :(UIImage *)theImage :(CGSize)theNewSize {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theNewSize, NO, 1.0);
CGFloat height = theImage.size.height;
CGFloat newHeight = 0;
newHeight = (theNewSize.width * height) / theImage.size.width;
newHeight = floorf(newHeight);
NSLog(@"new height image %f", newHeight);
[theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theNewSize.width, newHeight)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

inside layoutSubviews:

```
if(device == thisDeviceClass_iPhone5) {
    [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 255)]; //180
    offset = 0;
    padding = 5;
} else if(device == thisDeviceClass_iPhone6){
    [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 375, 255)]; //211
    offset = 25;
} else if(device == thisDeviceClass_iPhone6plus) {
    [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 414, 255)]; //233
    offset = 40;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is very old school. You are "hard coding" the size of the image which means that if next year Apple came up with a new iPhone that have, yet again, a different size you'll be in trouble. You should consider using auto-layout constrains which is Apple's recommended approach (here is a good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

You can also set the `ImageView.contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` which will do the crop and resize for you.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is bad code, it is a temporary solution. Just if I do not specify the exact dimensions of the image, it moves independently, and pass the dimensions of the screen in the custom cell class, I do not know how. There is no variable self.view. ...

Comment: I installed this contentMode but does not help the image distorted and understand why I can not strain.

Comment: did you set the imageView's  "Clip subviews" to YES?

Comment: included. This function has cut the upper part of the image.

Comment: if you don't want it to crop you can set the contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: If I turn this mode the image is compressed, I do not. Listen, "Clip subviews" included at the whole cell or image only. Just strange why diformiruetsya image when scrolling the table when we start the application are all very cool, I start flipping - all shifts.

Comment: i find solution. i remove         [cell layoutIfNeeded];
AND ALL okay